# Cannot install mongoDB on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I run the command `brew tap mongodb/brew` with no issues, but when I run `brew install mongodb-community` I receive the below error.

**Error :**

```
==> Installing mongodb-community from mongodb/brew
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/shilpakancharla/Library/Logs/Homebrew
```

How can I overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your Homebrew permission issue.

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Users/$USER/Library
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

Comment: I am still having some issues - in High Sierra, it does not seems like you can use `chown` on `/usr/local` (https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228). I used `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` but no luck. I am still unable to install mongoDB.

Comment: Mostly, it is permission issue. Can you run `sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Users/$USER/Library`, also updated my original answer.

Comment: I ran that command, and then the second command you listed in your original comment and received `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`. Wondering if this has something to do with High Sierra?

Comment: this might be something related too. https://discourse.brew.sh/t/problem-with-brew-update/5614/6

Can you run `brew config` and updated the original post?

Comment: so it seems like I was trying something else, and I uninstalled homebrew. Now, I am not able to install it back again and keep getting this error `Need sudo access on macOS!
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin` sorry for the back and forth. Could you please help me get past this one?

Comment: Sounds like you dont have sudo permission now?

Comment: exactly - I don't know why uninstalling Homebrew would cause me to lose sudo permission?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209968/discussion-between-chenrui-and-shilpa-kancharla).